# Export data into multiple csv files from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to export data from SQL Server to multiple `.csv` files based on customer id. It is possible with SSIS and Azure Data Factory, but I don't have access to that. Is there any way with SQL Server?

Right now, I am trying with `BCP` shell commands. I am facing some error with this code. Can anybody provide some assistance?

```
DECLARE @TestData20 TABLE(IntValCol INT, DateCol DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @TestData20 (IntValCol, DateCol) 
VALUES (1, '09/05/2020'), (2, '09/05/2020'), (3, '09/06/2020'), 
       (4, '09/06/2020'), (5, '09/07/2020'), (6, '09/07/2020'), 
       (7, '09/08/2020'), (8, '09/08/2020'), (9, '09/09/2020'), 
       (10, '09/09/2020'), (11, '09/10/2020'), (12, '09/10/2020') 
 
-- Declaring Variables
DECLARE @MinDate DATETIME, @MaxDate DATETIME,
        @FileName VARCHAR(30), @FilePath VARCHAR(100), 
        @BCPCommand VARCHAR(4000) 

--Assigning Values To Variables
SELECT @MinDate = MIN(DateCol) FROM @TestData20
SELECT @MaxDate = MAX(DateCol) FROM @TestData20

--Creating the loop
WHILE @MinDate <= @MaxDate
BEGIN
       --Setting up the filename and filepath
       SET @FileName = 'krishnaData'+ '_' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@MinDate,112) + '.csv'
       SET @FilePath = 'C:/Newfolder/' + @FileName

       --Fetching the data into a table
       SELECT * INTO new FROM @TestData20 WHERE DateCol = @MinDate 
       
       --Assigning the BCP statement to the variable
       SET @BCPCommand = 'BCP  master.dbo.new out '+@FilePath +  ' -T -w -t, '

       --Executing the BCP command through command-shell
       EXEC master ..xp_cmdshell @BCPCommand

       --Dropping the table, to utilize it again
       DROP TABLE new
       SET @MinDate = DATEADD(D,1,@MinDate)
END
```

I am getting errors on 7 lines:

> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is config
>
> ured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
>
> NULL

Comment: You might wanna include the error you're getting, so it's easier to help you

Comment: We can't run your code so have no idea what the error is... maybe include this?

Comment: Just now I have added the error at the bottom

Comment: Instead of weakening security to use `bcp`, why not use the built-in integration services?

Comment: Is there any way to store data in multiple csv files based on id using sql server

Comment: the bcp doesn't seem to be able to connect to default instance. What's the servername / ip / port when you connect by management studio? Send those to BCP

Comment: Here is the server name:DESKTOP-DQ26913\SQLEXPRESS

username: windows authentication

database:master

Answer (score 0):

try with the **SQL Server Import and Export Wizard**.
click on you database in the Object Explorer -> Tasks -> Export Data... -> in the destination view : choose Flat File Destination.

[image]

Comment: but I want to split and save the data into multiple csv files seperated by id column

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#:~:text=%5B%2DS%20%5Bserver_name%5B%5Cinstance_name%5D%5D%5D

try to add the -S parameter in the BCP command

Comment: I am not sure where to add in the code can you add this in my code